# Redirect subdomain to subdirectory - trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to redirect [abc].apps.example.com to the following apps.example.com/[abc] but still showing the using the [abc].apps.example.com in the url.

[abc] an be anything eg.

calendar.apps.example.com
books.apps.example.com
etc

With a bit of digging around and tweaking, I have the following setup but doesn't work when an ending slash is missing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Fix missing trailing slashes.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.apps\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.apps\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite sub domains.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.apps\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.apps\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%2/$0 [QSA,L]
```

When the following is entered:
calendar.apps.example.com/showcalendar/
it's redirected correctly to: apps.example.com/calendar/showcalendar/

But for when a trailing slash is missing
calendar.apps.example.com/showcalendar

I get a 404 error saying /calendar/calendar/showcalendar/ not found.

Please, if you know what's wrong with the above code or have a better solution do let me know.

Cheers,
Doggy

Comment: try with commenting your **rewritebase**

Comment: Punit, thanks for the suggestion.  It's still the same if i've commented out the rewritebase.

Comment: What i didn't mention in the above (i should have in the original post) is that the url became:
http://calendar.apps.example.com/calendar/showcalendar/

with the same 404: 
The requested URL /calendar/calendar/showcalendar/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following rewrite rule for adding trailing slashes.

```
# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```